# jquery doesn't change iframe html

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, iframe

I have this following code but it doesn't work on ipad

```
$('#video_container').html('<iframe width="560" height="335" src="'+URL+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>');
```

But it works

```
$('#video_container').html('<p>Hello world!!</p>');
```

The above code works on all browsers though well in all desktops.

Can anyone please give me any hints/suggestion.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can anyone tell me the reason. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options#answer-7469997

Comment: I tested it and it's working just fine. Are you sure the link you are trying to embed has a valid "X-Frame-Options" property?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried it without "allowfullscreen"?

```
$('#video_container').html('<iframe width="560" height="335" src="'+URL+'" frameborder="0">');
```